# Excel VBA script to save then disable *Update*

Tags: vba, excel

I have created an excel spreadsheet to use as a template for documentation. I have locked the workbook from being changed, with  the exception of the cells that need info entered. I then added a vba script that counts up every time the file is opened, with the password protection being unlocked then the vba script updates and password protection is enabled again. This is for my company's own internal document tracking. The problem I am running into is having the file auto save right after the vba script being executed and then have another vba script disable the save feature only allowing the save as feature. I don't want the file to be accidentally overwritten.

also I'd like a vba script to place a command button beside the file that can Save As with a standard excel format and uses cell data for file name if its possible.

This is what I have so far, I am very new to this.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="PassWord"

    Sheets(1).[I9] = Sheets(1).[I9] + 1

ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="PassWord"

ActiveWorkbook.Save

End Sub
```

Thank You in advance for your time.

***Update***

This is my code so far

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="PassWord"

    Sheets(1).[I9] = Sheets(1).[I9] + 1

ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="PassWord"

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    ChDir "C:\Users\BlahBlah\Desktop"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        "C:\Users\BlahBlah\Desktop\Quote Detail Log Proto.xltm", FileFormat:= _
        xlOpenXMLTemplateMacroEnabled, Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", _
        ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, CreateBackup:=False

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

the problem is now when save button or Ctrl+S is used it just saves overtop again, even though its a template format and should pop up a save as box.

my other road block is command button Save As using cells A1 , G9, and I9 as the file name. all the codes I have tried either don't work, or most likly I copied wrong/entered wrong info and just don't understand it at all.

Answer (score 0):

For the part about saving the file with a name from a cell, you can do something similar to:

```
Sub SaveAsCell()

Dim strName As String

    strName = Sheet1.Range("A1")

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs strName

Exit Sub
```

(From [OZGrid.com](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/save-as-cell.htm))

Also, looking at your code, the reason it's saving every time, is because you're telling it to save every time the workbook is opened.  Perhaps move the `ActiveWorkbook.Save` part to another macro.

Comment: That's fine I think, he wants a counter to increment every time the file is opened.

Comment: well I actually need it to auto save after my counter updates. but I think I got that problem solved I made it template which only allows save as. so I did that and ran a macro to auto save as over the original, which works until I get a pop up asking if I want to save over it which I want it to. how do I stop this from popping up?

Comment: Without seeing your code, try adding this JUST before, and JUST after your "Save" line:  `Application.DisplayAlerts = False`, then after, `Application.DisplayAlerts = True`.  If that doesn't do it, can you update your OP with the code you're now using?

Answer (score 0):

This code helps for disabling the Save command (just does nothing):

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
If SaveAsUI = False Then
Cancel = True

End If
End Sub
```

Source: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/22345-disable-%22save%22-option-file-menu.html

I don't know if this is what you are looking for. There seems (when I was testing this just now) to be one flaw with this solution: one can still "Save As" and then select the existing file :-)
I've tested it in Excel 2010.